# Door detection for topological map

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello I'm working with topological maps, and at this moment I need some implementation for door detection. Because this is challenge problem and is not my core of reasearch could someone suggest any implementation ready or nearly-ready to run? (in the sensor we have laser 2d and mono and stereo camara! )

Thanks,
Filipe

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32460/door-detection-for-topological-map/) by [Filipe Santos](https://answers.ros.org/users/907/filipe-santos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 346 on 2012-04-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The easiest, most "I'm trying to solve some other problem", and fastest way is probably to add ARTags to your doors. They're implemented in the [brown-ros-pkg](http://code.google.com/p/brown-ros-pkg/).

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2012-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0